# Even though File is Existing in my path, File.Exist condition is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I have the test.XML file in my D drive. when I attempt to run this code, it skips the condition despite the fact that record exists in my Disk. I had a go at evaluating the File extension moreover. I can't go inside the IF condition. could anybody offer assistance?ne help?

```
if(File.Exists(@"D:\\test.xml"))
{
  ..
  ..
}
```

Comment: To confirm - are you hosting your asp.net on your local machine, and is `D` a local hard drive on this same machine?

Comment: Are you sure that file exists in the D: root with that exact name (and not for instance "test.xml.txt" where the final .txt is hidden)? You need to specify the exact name including extension (and full folder path).

Comment: Please, check the comments below the answer. The correct code to use is: `if(File.Exists(@"D:\test.xml"))` (a single slash only). The verbatim strings do not use escape sequences, for the string is interpreted _literally_.

Answer (score 5):

You missed the `\`, as backslash is escape sequence you have to use an extra back slash in

path

```
if(File.Exist("D:\\test.xml"))
{
  ..
  ..
}
```

You can also use [verbatim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) string

```
if(File.Exist(@"D:\test.xml"))
{
  ..
  ..
}
```

**Edit** Based on comments

Use either `\` to escape the backslash in path **or** verbatim string, you are using both

Comment: wrongly typed the question. now check my question again

Comment: the same code i have. but problem is it skips the IF condition.

Comment: It's still not right.. you need to either escape the backslash like Adil has done, or use an @ in front of the string (like you have done too).. but both will not work

Comment: Use \ to escape or verbatim string, you are using both

Comment: please check my question posted @ top again..! i have already edited

Comment: File.Exists(@"D:\\test.xml")) should be File.Exists(@"D:\test.xml"))

Comment: You have still got it wrong.. you're trying too hard to escape that backslash.. you've overdone it!